# how to prevent the footerview show when pulltorefresh load all data?

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I use pulltorefreshListview in my project, I set Mode.Both. I want the result when I pull from end for loading more,and scroll the end ,already load all data ,I hope the footerview hide. but now when I scroll the listview to end ,the footerview is showing, How can I for that?

```
private void pullRefresh() {
    morelist.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
            if (refreshView.isShownHeader()) {
                //refresh
                new GetDataTask().execute();
            }else if (refreshView.isShownFooter()) {
                //load more
                number = number+20;
                new GetDataTask().execute();
            }
        }
    });
}


private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            if (isDown) {
                getData(number,"-1");
            } else {
                getData(number,"1");
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        morelist.onRefreshComplete();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code?

Comment: this is my code

Comment: yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onPostExecute() method

Comment: try : morelist.setRefreshing(false);

Comment: I try that , that's not ok , I pull from end when i load all data , that footerview  will show ,and always here , can't hide